# does media foundation support WTV?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

WTV is Microsoft's proprietary format. But when I use CreateObjectFromURL to open a WTV file, it simply complains "Could not open the file. (HRESULT = 0xc00D36C4)". How can I render a wtv file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the returned value: `0xC00D36C4` is `MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE` - "The byte stream type of the given URL is unsupported."

As for support in DirectShow see [Consumption of a WTV file in DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963726.aspx).

Comment: But media foundation is supposed to replace DirectShow. So why media foundation? It seems there is no advantage?

Comment: There has never been a promise to cover all DirectShow feature set. Why Media Foundation? You don't choose it only because MS tells you so. Instead, you pick what is better for you, in context of WTV you would perhaps choose DirectShow.

Comment: Another question. Why Microsoft is so insistent on developing Media programming in COM? Why they don't make a .NET library??

Comment: DirectShow was introduced years before .NET. At the time Media foundation was considered, .NET could be an option, but media APIs are sensitive to overheads, and fine control over details, and threading - things where native outperforms, and COM is a great glue to use MF API from managed environment anyway. MF COM interface is much more .NET friendly compared to DirectShow.